# play/stream audio and video on browser without an option to download

Tags: audio, streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming, jplayer

I have some audio and video files which will be served from server to browser on request. Now I need a way by which "Users can watch or listen to media but shouldn't be able to download in anyway (even with developer tools or download manager plugins)". Kindly share your ideas if you have had experience on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are streaming it to them you can't stop them downloading it as, in extreme cases, they can simply capture the network traffic.

It sounds like you may want to encrypt the content using one of the commonly used encryption techniques and then find a secure way to share the encryption key with your users and their devices/players. This way any captured or downloaded content will not be of use to anyone without the right key.

This is essentially what DRM technologies do so it would probably be worth you investigating them - you can integrate the functionality to your own sever or simply host your videos with a provider who provides the functionality and embed their video player on your site.